# object reference set to null on sqldatareader

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an issue with the following code,

```
 Protected Sub lnkEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnectionConnectionString").ToString())
    Dim command As New SqlCommand()





    Try

        Dim lnk As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
        Dim gr As GridViewRow = DirectCast(lnk.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim eid As String = GridView1.DataKeys(gr.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        ViewState("username") = eid
        sqlQry = "select FirstName, Surname, DepartmentName, ExtensionName, jobTitle, Pager, mailaddress, from employees1 where username='" & eid & "'"
        If connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            connection.Open()
        End If
        command = New SqlCommand(sqlQry, connection)

        dr = command.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then

            lblFirstName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("FirstName"))
            lblSurname.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("Surname"))
            lblDepartmentName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("DepartmentName"))
            lblExtensionName.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("ExtesionName"))
            lbljobTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("jobTitle"))
            txtPager.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("Pager"))
            txtEmail.Text = Convert.ToString(dr("mailaddress"))
            'lblFirstName.Text = dr("FirstName").ToString()
            'lblSurname.Text = dr("Surname").ToString()
            'lblDepartmentName.Text = dr("DepartmentName").ToString()
            'lblExtensionName.Text = dr("ExtensionName").ToString()
            'lbljobTitle.Text = dr("jobTitle").ToString()
            'txtPager.Text = dr("Pager").ToString()
            'txtEmail.Text = dr("mailaddress").ToString()
            'txtMobile.Text = dr("MobileNumber").ToString()
            'lblUserName.Text = dr("username").ToString()

        End If
        mpe2.Show()
    Catch
        Return
    Finally
        command.Dispose()
        dr.Close()
        connection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

I understand that the sqldatareader is throwing the null exception.

Ive tried

```
  dim dr as new sqldatareader
```

which states that it cant be accessed to it being "friend"

hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: On which line is the exception being raised ?

Comment: Your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks. Please use parameters.

Comment: on the dr.close() thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty catch block which is swallowing any exception.  You assume in `Finally` that `dr` is not null and try and close it.  I would do three things:

1. Add better exception handling so you know what the *real* problem is.
2. Add an `if Not (dr Is Nothing)` to your Finally block.
3. Switch to using parameters instead of concatenating SQL strings - the real problem may be a bad `eid` input value, and you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

At first look the query has a comma more than needed

```
"select FirstName, Surname, DepartmentName, ExtensionName, jobTitle, Pager, mailaddress------>,<---- from employees1 where username='" & eid & "'"
```

must be

```
"select FirstName, Surname, DepartmentName, ExtensionName, jobTitle, Pager, mailaddress from employees1 where username='" & eid & "'"
```

In debug mode (or if you can't getting out a log on a file) get the query you're executing and test directly on the db query editor and see if is working, then use it inside you code

Probably commenting the try for a while will give you a SqlException exception on dr = command.ExecuteReader() but instead you are getting the exception in the finally block because all the code if skipped.